# Union ALL query failed in VBA but ok in SQL

Tags: mysql, vba

I Tried to run the below Query but its showing an error incorrect syntax near 'unionselect' Can anyone help?

```
strsql = "select distinct a.LOCID,locnum,locname,streetname,city,county,statecode,state,peril,SITEDEDAMT,SITELIMAMT,COMBINEDDEDAMT,COMBINEDLIMAMT from eqdet a inner join loccvg b on a.LOCID=b.locid inner join loc c on b.LOCID=c.LOCID where PERIL=1" & _
   "union" & _
  "select distinct a.LOCID,locnum,locname,streetname,city,county,statecode,state,peril,SITEDEDAMT,SITELIMAMT,COMBINEDDEDAMT,COMBINEDLIMAMT from hudet a  inner join loccvg b on a.LOCID=b.locid inner join loc c on b.LOCID=c.LOCID where peril=2" & _
  "union" & _
    "select distinct a.LOCID,locnum,locname,streetname,city,county,statecode,state,peril,SITEDEDAMT,SITELIMAMT,COMBINEDDEDAMT,COMBINEDLIMAMT from todet a  inner join loccvg b on a.LOCID=b.locid inner join loc c on b.LOCID=c.LOCID where peril=3" & _
    "union" & _
   "select a.LOCID,locnum,locname,streetname,city,county,statecode,state,peril,SITEDEDAMT,SITELIMAMT,COMBINEDDEDAMT,COMBINEDLIMAMT from fldet a  inner join loccvg b on a.LOCID=b.locid inner join loc c on b.LOCID=c.LOCID where peril=4" & _
   "union" & _
 "select distinct a.LOCID,locnum,locname,streetname,city,county,statecode,state,peril,SITEDEDAMT,SITELIMAMT,COMBINEDDEDAMT,COMBINEDLIMAMT from frdet a  inner join loccvg b on a.LOCID=b.locid inner join loc c on b.LOCID=c.LOCID where peril=5" & _
 "union" & _
 "select distinct a.LOCID,locnum,locname,streetname,city,county,statecode,state,peril,SITEDEDAMT,SITELIMAMT,COMBINEDDEDAMT,COMBINEDLIMAMT from trdet a  inner join loccvg b on a.LOCID=b.locid inner join loc c on b.LOCID=c.LOCID where peril=6"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the error message I suspect you are concatinating a string to make the query. `unionselect` should be two words, seperated by a space. (`union select`) I think that in your code spaces are missing to separate keywords.

See:

```
"...where PERIL=1" & _ "union" & _ "select distinct..."
```

will produce

`...where PERIL=1unionselect distinct...`

output. Correct code (notice the spaces around the union):

```
"...where PERIL=1" & _ " union " & _ "select distinct ..."
```